# remove td class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` in which contains a `td class='small'` I want to use jQuery to remove this.

```
<td class="small" style="padding:8px 0;color:#999;vertical-align:middle;">
A bunch of gibberish...
</td>
```

In my main code I am using jQuery to extract a div from a file then replace the `div` in the main code with the extracted.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500" />
<title>Rooster Teeth News</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site/wwwRand1.css">
<?php 
include( 'site/simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html=file_get_html( 'http://roosterteeth.com/home.php'); 
$html->save('site/result.htm')                      
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="site/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function() {    
$('#postsArea').load('site/result.htm #postsArea');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="postsArea"></div>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is that I can only remove the 'td' after the 'div' has been replaced. If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: $('td.small').removeClass('small');

Comment: need to use callback of `load()` if element is part of new ajax content...see docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method has a callback function so you could use:

```
$('#postsArea').load('site/result.htm', function(){
    $('#postsArea td.small').removeClass('small')
});
```